# Include AngularJS module and controller names in $log output?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging, angularjs-scope, angularjs-log

I am investigating logging options and conventions in AngularJS.  I would like my `$log` output to contain both the `module` and `controller` names (similar to loggers in Log4j).  With the code below, I was able to inject the `controller` name into the `$scope`

```
var app = angular.module("demo", []);

app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$controller', [
        '$delegate',
        function ($delegate) {
            return function(constructor, locals) {
                if (angular.isString(constructor)) {
                    locals.$scope.controllerName =  constructor;
                }
                return $delegate(constructor, locals);
            }
        }]);
}]);

app.controller('SampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log) {
    $log.log("[" + app.name + "." + $scope.controllerName +"] got here");
}]);
```

I would like to solve this a better way.  Specifically:

1. Is there a better way to access the `controller` name that adding it to the `$scope`?
2. Is there a way to get the `module` name instead of fetching **"demo"** from the `.name` property of the module `app` ?
3. Similar to [Enhancing $log in AngularJs the simple way](http://blog.projectnibble.org/2013/12/23/enhance-logging-in-angularjs-the-simple-way/), what is the best way to inject formatting like prepending **"[module.controller]"** into the `$log.log()` calls?